# Comparing every element in a vector with the next one

Tags: rust

I want to compare every element of a vector with the next one. I found the following solution but it is not so readable.

```
struct Obj {
    i: u32,
}

impl Obj {
    fn is_valid_next(&self, next: &Obj) -> bool {
        self.i + 1 == next.i
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data: Vec<Obj> = vec![Obj { i: 0 }, Obj { i: 2 }, Obj { i: 2 }];
    let mut previous: Option<Obj> = None;
    let mut is_valid = true;
    for current in data.into_iter() {
        match previous {
            Some(p) => {
                is_valid = p.is_valid_next(&current);
                if !is_valid {
                    break;
                }
            }
            None => {}
        }
        previous = Some(current);
    }
    println!("is valid {}", is_valid);
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This can be done in several ways.

### Using `slice::windows`

[`slice::windows`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.windows):

> Returns an iterator over all contiguous windows of length size.

In this case, the window size will be `2` so `windows` will return an iterator which will mask 2 elements and it will move to the right on every iteration.

```
initial position : [|0, 5|, 10, 40, 30] // &[0, 5]
next position    : [0, |5, 10|, 40, 30] // &[5, 10]
```

Here is an applied solution to your problem:

```rust
fn main() {
    let data: Vec<Obj> = vec![Obj { i: 0 }, Obj { i: 1 }, Obj { i: 2 }, Obj { i: 3 }];

    let is_valid = data.windows(2).all(|w| w[0].is_valid_next(&w[1]));

    println!("Is consecutive -> {:?}", is_valid); // true
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=18823f458f70bcc6ac6c7986bf797c6a)

Please note that direct index access of a slice might cause a `panic`, but since the produced slice from `Windows` iterator will be the same size as the argument to `windows`, it will be fine to access elements directly by index as long as the index is less than the window size.

### Using `Iterator::zip`

You can compare the current element with the next one by using two different iterators of same `Vec` with `std::iter::Zip`.

The iterator elements from the first iterator (`data.iter()`) will represent the current element. Elements from the second iterator (`data.iter().skip(1)`) will represent the next element.

Here is the implementation:

```
fn main() {
    let data: Vec<Obj> = vec![Obj { i: 0 }, Obj { i: 1 }, Obj { i: 2 }];

    let is_valid = data
        .iter()
        .zip(data.iter().skip(1))
        .all(|(current, next)| current.is_valid_next(next));

    println!("Is consecutive -> {:?}", is_valid); // true
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=33782360231ec8b0a1c3bbcc2916fa30)

If you are sure your `Vec` is not empty, you can use slices to create the iterators: `&data[1..]` instead of `data.iter().skip(1)` ([sample](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3b40e7a2ddc6a5da3ee7e6619d4f6d96)). This will panic if you have an empty `Vec`.